# How to select trees where nodes are stored in separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, algorithm, recursion

**Lets say I have these tables:**

```
A| k     B| k | a     C| k | a     D| k | c     E| k | d     ...
-----    ---------    ---------    ---------    ---------
 | 1      | 1 | 1      | 1 | 1      | 1 | 2      | 1 | 2
 | 2      | 2 | 1      | 2 | 1      | 2 | 2
 | 3      | 3 | 1      | 3 | 3
                       | 4 | 1
```

**They can represent three tree structures like this:**

```
    _____A1_______            A2            A3            ...
   /  /  |  |  \  \                         |
  B1 B2 B3  C1 C2 C4                        C3
              /  \
             D1   D2
                  |
                  E1
```

**The rules for the mapping are:**

- The rows of one table are children of exactly one other table. I.e. all rows in D is children of rows in C (D.c maps to C.k).
- No limit to dept
- No limit to number of child nodes per node

**The goal is to select one row per leaf node.**

The content in the rows should be the same as what you find by traversing the trees from root nodes to a leaf nodes.

**For this example that would be:**

```
Ak | Bk | Ba | Ck | Ca | Dk | Dc | Ek | Ed
-------------------------------------------
 1 |  1 |  1 |    |    |    |    |    | 
 1 |  2 |  1 |    |    |    |    |    |  
 1 |  3 |  1 |    |    |    |    |    |  
 1 |    |    |  1 |  1 |    |    |    |  
 1 |    |    |  2 |  1 |  1 |  2 |    | 
 1 |    |    |  2 |  1 |  2 |  2 |  1 |  2
 1 |    |    |  4 |  1 |    |    |    |  
 2 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    
 3 |    |    |  3 |  3 |    |    |    |
```

I have already made a solution/algorithm that works. It will easily scale to bigger number of tables and depth by generating the select by recursion. However I'm not sure how the select will scale performancewise. Also, the select is not pretty and not easily readable for humans.

**How would you solve this?**

- The solution must be more or less portable between the major dbs.

**[Use this gist to create the example tables](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95f8d49c9971fda23d14)**

Comment: Is this just an academic exercise, or do you foresee some practical application?  If the latter, could you elaborate on the business requirements a little further (as there are much better ways to model graphs than this bizarre approach).

Comment: And you should show the "solution/algorithm" that you have made—how else are we to comment on its scalability (in respect of which indexing will of course be essential, yet none is defined in your gist)?

Comment: @eggyal: I am fairly new to databases, but I am a seasoned developer. Where I started working we have ~1000 of tables. (Some up to 20 years old). Some relates 1:N, some 1:1. I my mind that is a tree. We write our selects manually. Repetitive tasks is for computers, and declarative beats imperative. Therefore, my idea is that stating the tables involved and the keys linking them should be enough. Let the computers do the rest. Also the result will be transferred over network. So db is probably faster than us at removing duplicates, and we save bandwidth. Hence minimize rows.

Comment: @eggyal: Exactly because my solution may be bizarre. I want your take on this, alternative solutions, not tainted by my solution. When it comes to indexing, we add them as needed depending on the case. If a proposed solution requires some special index, just state it.

Comment: @eggyal: My solution is to build the table recursively from the leaf tables one level at a time up to the root. Like this: ED = (E left join D on ... union E inner join D where ...) Then: CDE = (C left join ED on .. union ...) Then: ACDE = (A left join ...) and so on. All combined with the where keyword. Giving you one select with roughly (not done the math) NlogN subselects where N is table count. This is just my first idea, NOT necessarily a clever one. That is why I am asking :)

Comment: @eggyal: In real life depth is probably never more that ~3, so the the general solution borders to academic exercise. However I usually find that solving the general problem gives great insight even for the simplest specific problem. The final algorithm tends to be simpler, more elegant and faster that the one you would end up write for only depth = 1,2,3 (without really understanding the underlying lines of the problem).

Comment: There are a few common ways to store tree structures in relational databases.  Some models, like the adjacency list, require recursive functions (not supported by all RDBMS) to perform commonly required behaviours like deep search.  Other models are more portable, but are a little harder to grasp.  Take a look into nested sets and/or transitive closure, and if neither suits your application then explain why and we might be able to make a better suggestion!  For an intro to both, I highly recommend Bill Karwin's presentation http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Comment: @Mathias I see you have `oracle` tagged. Take a look at the data dictionary that are available in Oracle and the numerous functions and features that are available in 11g or 12c. Your problem is likely more simple than you think. What version of the database are you using?

Comment: @Annjawn: That may have been misleading, not room for all tags. We support the RDBMS that the customer wants, more or less. Therefore we choose to keep to a very minimal common denominator when we write the SQL. Tricky stuff is done in code to be to portable across RDBMSs. (that means, among others, no triggers, no sets, no join deletes, no views, no blobs, .. :), pretty much SQL101)

Comment: @eggyal: Thanks for the link! The AL, PE and NS cannot be used as my tables contain completely different data (maybe my examples didn't explain that wery well). CT could be used, i guess, but again example only shows the case for one data type(one table). So it needs to be extended to N tables. Need to think more about that one.